# How to get real class names in Android Monitor when using Proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I enabled Proguard for my app and now when I get an exception, in Android Monitor I'm seeing something like

```
at com.mydomain.myapp.v.c(SourceFile:901)
at com.mydomain.myapp.v.a(SourceFile:1260)
```

In another app that I have, I also have proguard available, but I'm seeing something like

```
at com.mydomain.myotherapp.v.c(MainMenuScreen.java:948)
```

and I can click on the class name and Android Studio takes me to the exact line. I've tried copying the entire contents of the proguard file to the first app and nothing changes.

What is the setting in my project that makes Android Monitor have nice clickable links? In my proguard rules I have:

```
-keepattributes Exceptions, InnerClasses, 
                Signature, Deprecated, SourceFile, EnclosingMethod, LineNumberTable
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why you run proguard and obfuscate the code, that reason is not being able to do that! Else it would totally dismiss the point of obfuscation.

What you can do is to fetch your mapping.txt that is in your outputs folder and with the help of proguardgui.bat that is somewhere in your sdk folder you can get a normal stacktrace

Comment: Right, but my question is why do I have it in one app and not in another despite them having identical proguard rules?

Comment: I need to know why it happens in one app and not another despite them having the same keepattribute rules.